# Передача данных в python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Каким образом можно за одно нажатие кнопки передать текст переменной в две функции

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: word
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'Разобрать слово'
            on_press:   # И вот тут мне надо отправить word.text в метод pars
                        # и паралеьно в SettingScreen

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")
ans = ""


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def pars(self, text):
        global ans
        ans = text

    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: word
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'Разобрать слово'
            on_press:
                app.root.get_screen('menu').pars(self.text)
                app.root.get_screen('settings').pars(self.text)


<SettingsScreen>:

    BoxLayout:

        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")
ans = ""


# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def pars(self, text):
        global ans
        ans = text
        print(f"Call from <MenuScreen.pars> {text}")


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    def pars(self, text):
        print(f"Call from <SettingsScreen.pars> {text}")


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Так мне же нужен текст с TextInput,  а не с кнопки. И как ещё во второе окно попасть?

Comment: Каков вопрос - таков ответ!